# cv2.findCirclesGrid in python not working

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera

I want to calculate a calibration for my camera and I have this pattern but it for some reason doesnt recognise it.

```
calibration_pattern = cv2.imread('circles/IMG_9341.JPG')
gray_pattern = cv2.cvtColor(calibration_pattern, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Define chessboard size and criteria
pattern_size = (4, 11)  # Change accordingly based on your calibration pattern

# Find circle centers on the calibration pattern
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(gray_pattern, pattern_size, flags = cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID + cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING)
```

ret is always False

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOjr5.jpg)

I tried changing up the patterns, flags even other images but it is always False.

Comment: I think the pattern you're using is not the one expected by `cv2.findCirclesGrid`. The circles alternate positions between each row, try a pattern where they're all aligned.

Comment: @Tiphel that is what the `cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID` is for, so that it can detect asymmetric grids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fix would be to edit the `blobDetector` params. The default `blobDetector` does not suit your image

Your circles are quite big, and hence if you set the minimum and maximum area of the blob detector, everything should work fine. Here's how to do it:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("circles.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # read im
im_chess = im.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # convert to gray
blobParams = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params() # create a default blob detector param
blobParams.filterByArea = True # enable filtering by area
blobParams.minArea = 10000   # minimum area
blobParams.maxArea = 40000   # maximum area
blobDetector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(blobParams) # create the blob detector
ret, corners = cv2.findCirclesGrid(im, (4,11),
                                   flags = (cv2.CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID+cv2.CALIB_CB_CLUSTERING),
                                   blobDetector = blobDetector) # pass the blobDetector to the function
if ret == True: # if detected...
    corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), 
                                (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)) # refine corner location
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(im_chess, (4,11), corners2, ret) # draw the chessboard
```

This is the end result:

[image: Results]

Try to play around with other parameters if you want. [This is a nice tutorial](https://longervision.github.io/2017/03/14/ComputerVision/OpenCV/opencv-external-posture-estimation-circle-grid/).